# Magento Special Price display after expire

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How to display the special price after its expired in magento, the special price is not seen after the date is expired, need to show the special price after expiritation time also. How can this be achieved? any ideas pls

Comment: Special price is time framed only. Special price is removed after its time expired. You can put far future date.

Answer (score 0):

Just let the fields with Special Price To Date empty, validity will never expire:
[image]

If you for some reason need a date of special price expiration saved, but you don't want to use it to change real price, create new similar attribute only for internal purposes.